Unity: TextMeshPro 3D Object renders in different color than what it supposed to be
The main problem
So I'm making a little 2D game in Unity in a pixel style. I'm right now in the middle of making a cutscene when player gets any upgrade.
Problem is, I always used 3D TextMeshPro instead of TMP UI component because it means easy sorting order but when making the cutscene I noticed that the color of 3D object is different from what it is supposed to be. Compared to the UI object above, the 3D Text is much brighter and pale. Then I noticed the same stuff was happening in my HUD too.
If I use eyedropper to get the color from the UI, I get the exact same color. When I use it on the 3D object it changes.
I want to get rid of this problem without putting my head around UI TMP with no comfortable sorting attributes.
face color
Basically I've tried playing with every setting in TMP 3D object, nothing happened. I thought that, maybe, the problem is with the material or the font itself but nope, all fonts in 3D TMP has this problem in my project.

Goddamnit feels bad
I thought I searched all over the net for this but as soon as I posted I found some stuff that answers my questions.
Either put Color Space in Player->Other Settings from Linear to Gamma or make some turn-off-HDR scripts.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmesh-pro-colors-highly-inaccurate.693436/
